# How to do a dashboard on Ember.js (having a counter of itens in the application level)

Tags: javascript, api, ember.js

So, this is not that simple to explain, but I have my Ember app, with my routes, controllers and views etc, it's about jobs listings, this is the most important part of the app, but I also have other models, for users and companies. So, in the `ApplicationRoute` I'm doing this thing here:

```
renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ controller: 'jobs' });
}
```

because on my jobs controller I need to count the amount of listings I have, to display in a menu that shows up at every page, like this:
[image: jobsCount]

I'm getting this number by doing this at the `jobsController`:

```
jobsCount: function() {
    return this.get('model.length');
}.property('@each')
```

which works fine because my homepage is the listing of jobs, which calls `/api/jobs/` with all of them. The problem happens when I start the app in any other page, like accessing `/jobs/:id/` directly, `/admins/` or anything else, the count would be zero, since the `jobsController` is not loaded and I don't get the number of jobs from the api (accessing `/api/jobs/:id/` directly, for example). After accessing the homepage the number of ads load, since it calls `/api/jobs/` with all the jobs on it. So, one of the workarounds for this was setting `ApplicationsRoute`'s model to be jobs as well, which resulted in two requests every time the application loads for the first time, that was working fine but I don't like the idea of having to do two requests just to get a number, especially when most of the time the first page to be loaded is the homepage, resulting in two requests to the same URL (`/api/jobs/`).

Is there anyway to do this without doing two requests, like if I visit a job listing (`/jobs/:id/`) to force it to load `/api/jobs/` and then look up for the id, instead of loading `/api/jobs/:id/`, or this is not a good solution as well? Should I have a specific URL on the API just to load this numbers?

Is the question clear enough?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ultimately I decided to break DRY.  In your example this would mean rendering the job_count in the json rendered by all routes that could possibly be called when the user enters the application.  This makes the app's design slightly messy, but means that you never have to make multiple calls.

However, if your app gets to where there is a lot of unrelated data that ember needs access to when the user first loads the app, then you should make a url specifically for loading that data and yes, make two requests upon initial load.  As far as UX goes, a marginally longer initial load time is irrelevant because of the improvement ember gives for every route entered there-after.  Remember, by rendering client-side ember will always be slower upon initial load than a traditional server-rendered app anyway.
I'm afraid that's trade-off that has to be made.

Comment: It would be possible to just keep the solution I have for every time the user start the app at the homepage and do the extra request just when the user starts at another page?

Comment: Yeah I didn't notice that your app starts at a page where the call is already being made.  So yeah, just make the extra request at the other routes.  But you should probably just go ahead and load the jobs model.  Since jobs_count is a computed property, you can't set it directly or it will no longer be a computed property.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something more like this. In your `JobsRoute`, you can do something like this:

```
App.JobsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {       
        var jobs = this.store.find('job');
        jobs.then(function() {
             this.store.find('job', params.job_id);
        });
    }
});
```

First, we'd find all the jobs by calling `this.store.find('job')`. This will return a promise, which we wait for it to resolve and populate the store with all the jobs.  Then, we find the job in particular we're looking for. This way all the jobs are loaded, in just one request, and only one job is represented by your job controller.

Comment: I tried to do this, but I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined ` error

Comment: Do you know what line thats from?